# Running agents in "infinite" loop threads is wrong?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a web-crawler where the basic layout is a manager that runs agents that open connection, fetch the content and insert it in a database.

Each one of these agents run in a separate thread in a loop until the user send a stop signal. These agents get the tasks from the manager agent.

The problem is if an exception occurs in a agent, it can't be throwed to the interface (unless I use some observer to signal that an exception occurred).

I'm thinking that this design is wrong and the correct is create a finite task and putting they in the Executor (create a task for each URL to open connection, fetching content or insert into database).

I'm right that my current design is wrong and must change the layout? What is the right layout to use with multi threading where different agents do different parts of the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think you should be using the `Executors`.  If you submit `Callable` classes, you can throw from your spider agents and examine the returned `Future` which causes the exception to be thrown to the job submitter so it can be logged or displayed to your UI.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
Future<Void> future = pool.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
       // your agent code goes here
       // this can throw an exception in this block which will be re-thrown below
       return null;
    }
});
...
try {
   // then the exception will be thrown here for you to catch and log
   future.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
   // log the e.getCause() here
}
...
pool.shutdown();
```

Comment: Supposing this class is the Manager, I have three types of agents running in parallel. The tasks are done in sequence (open, fetch and insert, each one by one agent). I will need a loop in the Manager getting the results of each Executor. But the execution is blocked when the `get()` method is called, so I will need three managers, each one for running one executor to execution not be blocked while the get method is called?

Comment: Any reason not to call all 3 agents from a single thread @Renato?  Is there a reason to give a thread to each agent type?  Given that they each do a portion of the entire task, this seems like unnecessary complexity.

Comment: The reason is that open connections to sites are slow (I/O), so I have 10 threads open connections in parallel (example). Fetching the content is faster when the connection is already opened, so I have only 2 fetchers for 10 openers. If the openers are fetching, they aren't opening connection and slowing down the crawling. And the inserter is only one thread because is the fastest operation and in this way, it will use only one database connection. If openers or fetchers are inserting in the database, one database connection for each one must be opened.

Comment: This is my logic, I'm not sure if it is correct (if is wrong, please tell me), but the first thing I did was putting the entire process in one thread as you suggested, but after, splitting into agents the code become more clean, coherent and fast.

Comment: Well you certainly can do this although the complexity is higher.  I recommend having 3 different pools so you can change your thread counts per pool.  You should use the `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor where you can inject a `BlockingQueue`.  So each agent after they have done their work will put the `Job` into the next `BlockingQueue` for the next thread pool to process.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try this solution later and see if I get best management than the current layout.